# How can I run a big task in two instances in a cluster using Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I would like to run a java task in two instances sharing each other in a cluster using Hazelcast. So that, task can be completed faster rather than running in a single instance. Please help!

Comment: What did you try?, any code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not very clear from the question you have posted. Your big task may be doing one the following things.

1. Processing data (Data intense) stored in hazelcast distributed data
   structures.
2. Number crunching (CPU intense) operations with limited or no
   data from hazelcast.

In both the cases, you can make use of the distributed implementation of ExecutorService in hazelcast. See below link :

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IExecutorService.html

For case 1) since hazelcast partitions the data into multiple nodes (instances), you can execute your task on the owner of the key by calling executeOnKeyOwner() method as follows.

Sample Code

```
    HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    Map<Integer, String> map = hz.getMap("yourMap");
    for (int key = 0; key < 100; key++)
        map.put(key, "someValue");
    IExecutorService executor = hz.getExecutorService("executor");
    for (Integer key : map.keySet())
        executor.executeOnKeyOwner(new YourBigTask(), key);
```

YourBigTask is your "big task class"  will implement `Runnable` and `Serializable` interfaces and do the necessary processing inside run() method. If you need to make you use of hzinstance inside `run()`, implement `HazelcastInstanceAware` as well.

For case 2) you can just call

```
    executor.executeOnAllMembers(new YourBigTaskClass());
```

which will execute your task on all of the known cluster members.

Hope this helps. I would still encourage you to take a look into other methods of `IExecutorService` and use the one that suits your problem in the best way.